# Перемещение полей (виджетов) в окне с зажатой ЛКМ

Tags: python, pyqt5

Я хочу реализовать свободное перемещение полей по окну с помощью мыши, вверх или вниз в пределах одного пространства. Пример такого поведения есть в досках Trello. 
[image: Пример]

Я понимаю что тут нужно задействовать функцию mouseMoveEvent с условием что-то вроде `if self.offset is not None and event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and self.itemField_001:`, но как это реализовать так чтобы перетаскиваемые поля вставлялись между другими полями, я не имею представления. Подскажите как написать подобное поведение, если это конечно не займёт целый проект с ООП и подключением других библиотек.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `QListWidget` и `Drag-N-Drop`

Answer (score 0):

В общем по наводке Alexander Chernin занесло меня на зарубежные форума где я и получил весь нужный синтаксис с объектами. Жалко что итемам нельзя прописывать `setStylesheet` внутри списка. Таким образом я не понимаю как можно красиво оформить каждое поле.
И с уникальностью полей пока не разобрался. Если через for генерировать список, например с базы SQL. Тут без eval() наверное не обойтись для уникальных переменных, хотя я всегда считал это костылём.
И ещё пока не понимаю как сохранять позиции при закрытии окна. Видел в документации `QListWidget::itemFromIndex`, но мне IDE пишет что вообще не знает модуля itemFromIndex, если конечно это вообще то что нужно. А пока оставляю свой пример для русскоязычных камрадов.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.field = QLabel("")
        self.grid = QHBoxLayout(self.field)
        self.grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.mark = QLabel("Item 6")
        self.grid.addWidget(self.mark)
        self.btn = QPushButton('')
        self.btn.setMaximumWidth(30)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.markInput = QLineEdit(self.field)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.markInput)

        self.list = QListWidget(centralWidget)
        self.list.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.list.setDragDropOverwriteMode(True)
        self.list.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        # self.list.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove) -- ЧТо это и чем отличается, я хз, но оно работает так же как и с предыдущей строкой
        self.list.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.list.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        self.list.addItem("Item 1")
        self.list.addItem("Item 2")
        self.list.addItem("Item 3")
        self.list.addItem("Item 4")
        self.list.addItem("Item 5")

        self.item = QListWidgetItem()
        #self.item.setText("Уникальный итем (Item 6)")
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QPixmap('icons/Apagar/cil-minus.png'),
                       QIcon.Normal, QIcon.On)
        self.item.setIcon(icon)
        self.list.addItem(self.item)
        self.item.setBackground(QColor(120, 180, 60))
        # Что такое setData и что за роли в первом аргументе я не понял. Оф. документация написана для кого-то ещё, но не для новичков как я.
        self.item.setData(36, "Updated!")
        self.item.setForeground(QColor(20, 80, 160))
        self.list.setItemWidget(self.item, self.field)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
    w.resize(260, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: PandaStock, ваш ответ не соответствует заголовку вашего вопроса.

Comment: @S. Nick, Исправил